# Use python script to prepare command line options

Tags: python, bash

I am writing a python script to prepare command line options for another command (`lame`, but the issue is interesting irrespective of that). My plan is to use my script in this way:

```
lame $(python my_script.py)
```

I don't want to call lame from within my script, because I still want to be able to add additional options.

My problem is that `print`-statements from within my script get masked. So if `my_script.py` looks like this:

```
print('--tt "Some title" "a quoted filename.wav" "a quoted filename.mp3"')
```

Then the quotes are ignored and `lame` receives the arguments `['--tt', '"Some', 'title"', '"a', 'quoted', 'filename.wav"', '"a', 'quoted', 'filename.mp3"']` and obviously is not able to make any sense of it. How should the print command in python look to make sure the outer command receives the arguments `['--tt', 'Some title', 'a quoted filename.wav', 'a quoted filename.mp3']`?

Note: I'm writing the command line arguments as they would be passed to python's `subprocess` module.

Comment: "I don't want to call lame from within my script, because I still want to be able to add additional options." Calling `lame` from inside your script doesn't prevent you from adding additional options, as long as you write your script appropriately.

Comment: Agreed, I could simply append either all or some of `sys.argv`, but again, that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that bash only does quoting and expansion once, so it won't do quoting again on the output of your python script. To fix this do:

```
eval lame $(python my_script.py) more args
```

eval re-runs the quoting and expansion rules on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the arguments (e.g. filenames) do not contain newline characters,
would you please try:

my_script.py:

```
args = ['--tt', 'Some title', 'a quoted filename.wav', 'a quoted filename.mp3']
print('\n'.join(args))
```

bash script:

```
readarray -t args < <(python my_script.py)
mylame "${args[@]}"
```

The python script merges the argument list with a newline character
as a delimiter,
then the bash script splits the string on the newline characters and
assigns an array to retrieve the list of arguments.
As an edge case, if the filenames may contain newline characters, you can
pick another character as the delimiter. The null character will be the
safest choice.

Comment: Although I like this answer, it's quite a lot of extra code, making it a bit cumbersome to run this on the bash side. If this was my only option, I would probably go with @larsks' approach from the comment.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. My personal opinion is to avoid using `eval` unless there is no other choice && the input string is fully under one's control.